# Generics: cast derived class back to it's parent super class

Tags: c#, oop, generics, polymorphism

I have three base classes:

```
public class ItemBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductBase<T> : ItemBase
    where T : ItemBase
{
    public List<T> Modifiers { get; set; }
    public List<T> GroupModifiers { get; set; }
}

public class ModifierBase<T> : ItemBase
    where T : ItemBase
{
    public List<T> ChildModifiers { get; set; }
}
```

And two derived classes:

```
public class Product : ProductBase<Modifier>
{
    public string Some_Product_Specific_Property { get; set; }
}

public class Modifier : ModifierBase<Modifier>
{
    public string Some_Modifier_Specific_Property { get; set; }
}
```

The intent behind all this is to have different sets of derived classes like `Product` and `ProductFromOtherSystem` each with it's own specific properties but with the same basic properties.

And now I need to process basic properties of any class derived from `ProductBase<T>`.
For this purpose I want to use something like this:

```
public static void DoSomething(ProductBase<ModifierBase<ItemBase>> item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

The issue here is that I cannot pass parameters to it:

```
Product product1 = new Product();
DoSomething(product1);

ProductFromOtherSystem product2 = new ProductFromOtherSystem();
DoSomething(product2 as ProductBase<ModifierBase<ItemBase>>);
```

The error is like

> Cannot convert type _ to _ via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

I've tried to downcast it somehow but have not found any solution. I wonder if it is possible to do it?

Comment: I think you are making some confision between template classes ond derived classes. I think you can acheive the same gaol without any <T> template syntax. Just think of it: having the same basic properties and then specific properties is exactly what inheritance is for

Comment: So `Product` and `Modifier` are in separate project, as well as `ModifierBase` and `ProductBase`. And `DoSomething()` is in third project. The difficulty is with `Modifier` and all the `List<Modifier>` properties. If I get read of `<T>` then how I get access from `DoSomething()` to properties like `public List<T> Modifiers { get; set; }`? Therefore I should declare them in base class as `public abstract List<ModifierBase> Modifiers { get; set; }`. Since I've declared them in base I cannot now override it in derived with something like `public override List<Modifier> Modifiers { get; set; }`